# DIV that is scrollable to reveal DIV underneath

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, effect

I have a number of DIVs that I have positioned on top of one another.

What I am trying to get to is being able to scroll the top DIV and then once at the bottom of the DIV, reveal the DIV underneath.

Here is where I've got to so far:

https://codepen.io/dadofgage/pen/yMqZaj

```
<style>
    #container {
    position: relative;
}

.overlay, .overlay2, .overlay3, 
.content{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.overlay3{
    z-index: 8;
    background: #000;
    color:#fff
}

.overlay2{
    z-index: 9;
    background: #c00;
}

.overlay{
    z-index: 10;
    background: #ccc;
}
</style>


<div id="container">
<div class="overlay3">This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  This is the top div of content.  </div>
<div class="overlay2">This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  This is the SECOND div of content.  </div>
<div class="overlay">This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  This is the THIRD div of content.  </div>
<div class="content">This is the BOTTOM div of content.  This is the BOTTOM div of content.  This is the BOTTOM div of content.  This is the BOTTOM div of content.  This is the BOTTOM div of content.  This is the BOTTOM div of content.  This is the BOTTOM div of content.  This is the BOTTOM div of content.  This is the BOTTOM div of content.  This is the BOTTOM div of content.  This is the BOTTOM div of content.  This is the BOTTOM div of content.  This is the BOTTOM div of content.  This is the BOTTOM div of content.  This is the BOTTOM div of content.  This is the BOTTOM div of content.  This is the BOTTOM div of content.  This is the BOTTOM div of content.  This is the BOTTOM div of content.  </div>
```

Comment: You are required to showa minimal example of the code that shows the problem here, not a third party web site that can disappear tomorrow. Show us you jQuery.

Comment: I dont have any other code - that's what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: @Mike what have you tried? This is only CSS and HTML. Where is your JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making use of `.scrollTop()` and then conditionally reveal them based on that. For example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/89at6t77/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="o-3" class="overlay">This is contents #3.</div>
  <div id="o-2" class="overlay hidden">This is contents #2.</div>
  <div id="o-1" class="overlay hidden">This is contents #1.</div>
  <div id="o-0" class="content hidden">This is content.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 1500px;
}

.overlay,
.content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 150px;
}

#o-3 {
  z-index: 8;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff
}

#o-2 {
  z-index: 9;
  background: #c00;
  top: 300px;
}

#o-1 {
  z-index: 10;
  background: #ccc;
  top: 600px;
}

#o-0 {
  top: 900px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var boxHeight = $("#o-3").height();
  $(window).scroll(function(e) {
    currentPos = $(window).scrollTop() + boxHeight;
    if (currentPos > 320) {
      $("#o-2").fadeIn();
    }
    if (currentPos > 620) {
      $("#o-1").fadeIn();
    }
    if (currentPos > 920) {
      $("#o-0").fadeIn();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you for your assistance!  What if I want to place the DIV's on top of one another so as they scroll the one underneath is revealed?

If I use position:absolute and top:0 is does that but since you are scrolling you have technically moved the parent div up

Comment: I've updated your fiddle just a bit to try and better show the final effect that I'm going for - my next hurdle is getting variable heights in these DIVs

https://jsfiddle.net/dadofgage/0k7az7mL/

Comment: @Mike it can be done. If the height is variable, you just have to get the height of each `div`, maybe stored in an array, and adjust accordingly when you show and hide different parts.